# Parse.com: How to apply filters on various ids

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using parse.com for my service side purpose of my app.
 I have designed a filter screewn with some primary filter items. Inside the primary filter items I've some secondary filter items.
 User can select multiple secondary item (all have unique ids).
Now I wish to fetch data on applying those filter items. Any example/ idea of such query would be helpful.

Comment: can you share what have you done till now? 
Create ParseQuery object for your table and use whereEqualTo()

Comment: @virendrao I have a parse table filter that has a primary Filter item list and also for each primary item there is list of secondary Filter item list

Comment: Could you update your question to show what these filters are and how you are constructing your query at the moment...